# Mix and match class in C++/MFC

Tags: c++, class, mfc, refactoring

I'm trying to re-factor a code base, and there is some common functionality among unrelated classes that I'd love to unite. I would like to add that functionality in common base class, but I'm not sure if it's clean and good approach.

Say I have `CMyWnd` class and `CMyDialogEx` class, both different, so they cannot inherit from one base class. I want to add a button to both classes and add the message handlers to both classes as well.

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
CMyWnd : public CWnd, public COnOkBtnFunctionality, public COnCancelBtnFunctionality
CMyDialogEx: public CWnd, public COnOkBtnFunctionality
```

Where `COnOkBtnFunctionality` would define `CButton m_buttonOk`, and all the `afx_msg` functions it should have. And so on.

Is this approach doable/good? Or are there better patterns I should resort to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're experiencing problems because of the design of `COnOkBtnFunctionality`, which wants you to use inheritance just for code reuse.

A quick reminder: **Inheritance is not designed for code reuse, it's designed for introducing abstraction.**

Or in other words: Is your CMyWnd a specific kind of `COnOkBtnFunctionality`, or does it  *have* `COnOkBtnFunctionality`?

Let me redirect you to Jeff Attwood for some more on the topic: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/inherits-nothing.html

---

Basically you're wanting to use multiple superclassing to implement the [Mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) functionality. Such implementation has some merits, but also drawbacks.

**Consider how you can implement COnOkBtnFunctionality and family so that they will be expected to be used as components, not superclasses of your a Window class.** It's certainly possible and you're likely to like the result.

Alternatively, one thing I can recommend you to consider is the **[Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)**, which may possibly be exactly what you need. It has the advantage that the "extensions" may be chosen and applied selectively in runtime easily.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't done much MFC in years, but from a purely OO perspective, this smacks of bad design. You should look at composition, in reality both windows own instances of a button - why the heck would you derive from it? Let's say for argument's sake you now implement more types of buttons, do you intend to derive from all of them?

Comment: Yes, deriving seems wrong, but I don't want to retype the CButton in each class, including different OnCtlColor messages and so on, I want to group common things into another class so that both windows could just reuse them. But again CWnd != CDialogEx, so I cant use a common base class. I can't seem to find a good article on composition pattern...

Comment: Like I said, my MFC is very rusty, but in Swing for example, you can encapsulate all the functionality you want into your own button class derived from (whatever - say `JPanel` for ex.), and then a window will simply have an instance of this rather than `JButton`. Can you not do the same? Importantly, in the ctor of the derived button, provide the instance of the window (say through some form of base interface) to callback for handling events on that button...

Comment: Message handlers are implemented as a combination of member function and message table entry, which forces inheritance rather than composition. Probably one reason why MFC gets so much hate.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance (or public inheritance at least) defines a *is-a* relationship. Is your window a button functionality? Or does your window *have* a button functionality? Obviously it's the latter, so I suggest to go for composition (or maybe private inheritance - see this [FAQ article](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.2)).

Answer (score 2):

Composition would be the right design decision; do not inherit.

If you have a special type of button that can be reused, create one: `class MyButton : public CButton`

If `MyButton` need access to methods from `CMyDialogEx` and `CMyWnd`, extract the common methods in a virtual class ([strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)) and derive from it. You can use the `MyButton`'s constructor to place the instance of virtual class, so MyButton's methods can access the *real* implementation.

I can recommend Alan's and James's book **[Design Patterns explained -- A new perspective on object-oriented design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321247140)** (ISBN-13: 978-0321247148):

[image]

It's a great book about *has-a* and *is-a* decissions, including cohesion and coupling in object-oriented design.